# Iframe not loading iframe internal links at the top of the iframe/parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a webpage (called PageA) that has a header and a main navigation bar and then simply includes an iframe. Lets call the page within the iframe PageB. PageB simply has a list of products but there are a lot of products so you have to scroll down on PageA to view them all.

When I scroll down PageA to see the bottom of pageB and click on a product link it looks like it takes me to a blank page. What actually happens is that it brings up the product image and description but since the page that just has one product and its description is much shorter in height, the scroll bar stays at the same location and doesn't adjust for it. I have to scroll up to the top of the page to view the product, description and to see the add to cart button.

Is there anyway when I click a link on a page that is within an iframe, the outer pages scroll bar goes back up to the top?

```
<iframe src="shop.undergloled.com";; onload="window.scroll(0,0)"; width="980" height="1400" frameborder="0" style="display:block seamless;"> </iframe>
```

Comment: <iframe src="http://shop.undergloled.com"; onload="window.scroll(0,0)"; width="980" height="1400" frameborder="0" style="display:block seamless;"> </iframe>

Comment: Can you create a JSfiddle please

Comment: It would probably be easier to just view the website its to much code for jsfiddle to handle. The url is www.undergloled.com, once there navigate to the Store Home page, and scroll down towrds the bottom of the page where there is a list of products with prices next to them, if you click one of those product links it will load the product page but you will see alot of blank white because it loads the page where the link was on the home page as opposed to the top of the iframe

Comment: It's best to post an example of your code and a fiddle to keep it to this website

Comment: I tried it keeps crashing because its to much for it to handle.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<iframe src="http://shop.undergloled.com" onload="window.scroll(0,0)" width="980" height="1400" frameborder="0" style="display:block;"></iframe>
```

Comment: I just tried that kamuken still having the same issue of it loading the product page to low.

Comment: body.scrollTop is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollTop' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollTop' only if in quirks mode.
body.scrollLeft is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollLeft' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollLeft' only if in quirks mode

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<iframe src="http://shop.undergloled.com" onload="window.scroll(0,0)" width="980" height="1400" frameborder="0" style="display:table !important;"></iframe>
```